# stuck on default Ubuntu wallpaper, no ubuntu desktop after login

Tags: 18.04, grub2, gnome, upgrade, desktop-environments

Hi all I had a dual boot Windows + Ubuntu which I recently removed and switched back the Windows boot loader. Now again I wanted to install Ubuntu 18.04 which give me some issues.

when I plugin the live USB, it asks *Try Ubuntu* or *Install Ubuntu*, I selected *Install Ubuntu* and then it hangs with the image below.

---

UPDATE: Ok now, I have my 18.04 OS on my PC, the process was a long run but was able to get my 18.04 by installing 16.04 first later upgrading to 18.04.

I'm able to login but the same screen is present (basically no desktop). Hopefully, I'm able to use mouse operations and even open a terminal after a right click.

Update 2: I tried `sudo gnome-shell --replace`, it gave me some messages saying the following :

```
Window manager warning: Unsupported session type.
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to launch manually `gnome-shell`?

Comment: just now I tried sudo gnome-shell --replace it gave me a some messages saying the following Window manager warning: Unsupported session type.